# Error from chokidar while using react-aad-msal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chokidar, react-aad-msal

I am working with azure active directory and I get this weird module not found error followed by a chokidar error :

```
./node_modules/react-aad-msal/dist/commonjs/MsalAuthProvider.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'msal' in 'C:\Users\paull\Monitoring_SOT\monitoring_sot\node_modules\react-aad-msal\dist\commonjs'
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys'
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\pagefile.sys'
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\swapfile.sys'
```

The purpose of this part is to create a authProvider.
I am using create-react-app and this is my authProvider. Using the latest versions of everything.

```
    //Configuration
    const config = {
        auth: {
            authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common',
            clientId: '<clientid>',
        },
        cache: {
            cacheLocation: "localStorage",
            storeAuthStateInCookie: true
        }
    };
    //Paramètres 
    const authenticationParameters = {
        scopes: [
            'profile.read'
        ]
    };
    //Options
    const options = {
        loginType: LoginType.Redirect
    }
    export const authProvider = new MsalAuthProvider(config, authenticationParameters, options)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact when you install the npm react-aad-msal it does not add the msal dependency to your project.
You should do `npm i msal`
letting this here so people could know